# Chrome devtools snippets disappear

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

In the Chrome devtools Sources tab, I have an issue that it seems there's a collapsing problem when there's a conflict at creating a snippet.

In order to reproduce, one way would be simply: 1. open two tabs 2. open devtools window on each tab 3. create a new snippet in one devtools window, let's say the created snippet name is `Script snippet #93`. 4. Write some code on the snippet `Script snippet #93` 5. create a new snippet in the one another devtools window, the created snippet name is `Script snippet #93` as well, as it has been automatically generated 6. open a new tab, open devtools window, check the content of the snippet `Script snippet #93`. You wouldn't see the content you wrote in the step 4, it has been disappearing somehow.

So, I wonder:

1. Is the issue recognized? Any fix or workaround out there?
2. Is there any way to restore the disappearing (lost?) snippets?

Thanks.